# Show data in Meteor react.Component

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-component

I am working meteor js. I have faced a problem because I am new in this environment. I am working on the update page. I can fetch data `console.log('Update 1', updateData);`. But how to show previous data in my input field value from `updateData`?

```
export default class EditEvent extends React.Component{

    EventUpdate(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Data submited for updated');


    }

    render(){
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id);

        Meteor.subscribe('allowedData');
        let updateData = Events.findOne({_id:this.props.match.params.id});
        console.log('Update 1', updateData);

        return(
            <div>
                <form className="upload-event-from" onSubmit={this.EventUpdate.bind(this)}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input 
                            value=""
                            type="text" 
                            className="form-control" 
                            id="event_title" 
                            placeholder="Event Title" 
                            name="title"
                        />
                        <span className="error-message">Error Message</span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-group fg-icon">
                        <label>Upload Video</label>

                        <input type="file" className="form-control-file form-control" id="exampleFormControlFile1" id="videoupload" />

                        <img src="/img/icons/video.png" alt="Video" />
                    </div>

                    <div className="user-type">
                        Event Status


                    </div>
                    <span id="message" ></span>

                    <center>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn app-btn">Update</button>
                    </center>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the package `react-meteor-data` which has been specifically designed to pass reactive data down to a React component in a Meteor application.

[Here is the documentation](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/tree/devel/packages/react-meteor-data)

In this case you would need to do:

```
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class EditEvent extends React.Component{
  EventUpdate(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Data submited for updated');
  }

  render(){
      const {
        loading,
        updateData,
      } = this.props;

      return loading ? null : (
          <div>
              { console.log('eventData', eventData) }
              <form className="upload-event-from" onSubmit={this.EventUpdate.bind(this)}>
                  <div className="form-group">
                      <input 
                          value=""
                          type="text" 
                          className="form-control" 
                          id="event_title" 
                          placeholder="Event Title" 
                          name="title"
                      />
                      <span className="error-message">Error Message</span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="form-group fg-icon">
                      <label>Upload Video</label>

                      <input type="file" className="form-control-file form-control" id="exampleFormControlFile1" id="videoupload" />

                      <img src="/img/icons/video.png" alt="Video" />
                  </div>

                  <div className="user-type">
                      Event Status


                  </div>
                  <span id="message" ></span>

                  <center>
                      <button type="submit" className="btn app-btn">Update</button>
                  </center>
              </form>
          </div>
      );
  }

}

export default withTracker(() => {
 const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('allowedData');

 return {
   loading: !subscription.ready(),
   updateData: Events.findOne({_id:this.props.match.params.id}),
 };
})(EditEvent);
```

In this example we are using the `withTracker` function to create a HOC (Higher Order Component) which subscribes to your Meteor subscription and will pass the data down as props when it changes.

If you don't understand how this works I really suggest you do the Meteor react tutorial - it will teach you how to implement subscriptions properly in React applications.

Comment: You may also want to checkout https://github.com/bcherny/undux as state management, it can provide initial state to react components when Meteor subscription is not ready.